# how to make helm template render template only once

Tags: kubernetes-helm, helm3

i have values.yml that can render deployment, there are two components. here my values.yml example

```yaml
workers:
          - name: default-worker
            metadata:
              name: default
              component: web-server
            serviceAccountName: default-worker-account
          - name: data-worker
            metadata:
              name: data
              component: web-server
            serviceAccountName: data-worker-account
```

this is the deployment.yml

```yaml
{{- if $.Values.workers -}}
{{- range $worker := $.Values.workers -}}
{{- $fullName := printf "%s-%s" (include "chart-app.fullname" $) $worker.name -}}
{{- $name := printf "%s-%s" (include "chart-app.name" $) $worker.name -}}
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: {{ $fullName }}
```

it will render two deployment of worker deployment.

```yaml
# Source: rails-app/templates/worker.yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: default-worker
# Source: rails-app/templates/worker.yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: data-worker
....
```

how to just render one deployment? for example just

```yaml
# Source: rails-app/templates/worker.yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: data-worker
```

i need to extract the result but i only need one deployment rendered

thanks in advance

Comment: If you would like to create only one deployment, why would you need to create two items in the `workers` list in the values file?

Comment: so it needed to be two workers deployment, but i need to do something with the render result, i can't find how to grep only one using grep command, so i think is there any way to render only one

Comment: Is my response below helpful? If so, please consider accepting it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would do the trick

```
{{- if $.Values.workers -}}
{{- with (first $.Values.workers) -}}
{{- $fullName := printf "%s-%s" (include "chart-app.fullname" $) .name -}}
{{- $name := printf "%s-%s" (include "chart-app.fullname" $) .name -}}
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: {{ $fullName }}
{{end}}
{{end}}
```